# Since I updated to iOS 7, my OverDrive Media app crashes every time I try to use it. What to do?

Tags: applications, crash, ios

My OverDrive Media app crashes every time I try to open a book. This never happened before I updated my iPad mini to iOS 7. I can open the app fine and go to the NYPL page, but as soon as I try to open any title the app crashes.

I've tried turning my iPad off then on again, but it still happens. I updated the OverDrive Media app before I downloaded iOS 7 and it was fine then. I don't particularly want to uninstall it then download it again, so if there's any other solution please let me know!

Comment: You should report the issue to the developer of the application. Since it was working correctly prior to the upgrade to iOS 7, it is almost certainly something outside of anyone's control but theirs.

Answer (score 2):

This is [already a known issue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/overdrive-media-console-library/id366869252?mt=8) with the app crashing on iOS 7, they'll put out a fix soon.

> The upgrade to iOS7 has resulted in problems for many OverDrive Media Console users.
>
> We are working on getting a new version into the App Store. If you do
>   not want to wait for the fixed version, you can complete the following
>   steps -- but note in advance that they are not ideal as re-installing
>   will clear your bookshelf, history, and app settings...
>
> 1. Uninstall OMC.
> 2. Re-install OMC.
> 3. Re-authorize your device with your Adobe ID when prompted.
> 4. Download your title(s) again.